# How can I change Github markdown background?

Tags: html, css, github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I want to change background of github markdown file. How can I do it? Is there specific markdown command to do that or maybe some HTML or CSS code? Or some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to do that.

In this file you'll find available HTML tags in github-flavored markdown:
https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-pipeline/blob/main/lib/html_pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb
(this is linked to by Github's README themselves)

It is also said [here](https://github.com/github/markup/tree/master#github-markup) that:

> The HTML is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as script tags, inline-styles, and class or id attributes.

Comment: Correct URL: https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-pipeline/blob/main/lib/html_pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb

Comment: Thanks @phd, updated my answer with the new url!